# Self-loop arrowhead different, cannot change

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows

I am making a presentation with beamer that has figures drawn by `tikz`. I set the arrowstyle for the `path` in the figure, but the self-loop arrowheads are different. Try to specify it locally, no change.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle, draw] (A) at (0, 0) {A};
  \node[circle, draw] (B) at (2, 0) {B};
  \path[->, thick, blue, -{Latex[length=2mm]}]
  (A) edge [bend left=20] (B)
  (B) edge [bend left=20] (A)
  (B) edge [out=45, in=315, loop] (B);
  % or (B) edge [out=45, in=315, loop, -{Latex[length=2mm]}] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: example]

It happens using any theme, I only have the packages `tikz` and `arrows.meta` loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
  \node[circle, draw] (A) at (0, 0) {A};
  \node[circle, draw] (B) at (2, 0) {B};
  \path[->, thick, blue]
  (A) edge [bend left=20] (B)
  (B) edge [bend left=20] (A)
  (B) edge [out=45, in=315, loop] (B);
  % or (B) edge [out=45, in=315, loop, -{Latex[length=2mm]}] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is because `every loop` is initially set to `->,shorten >=1pt` hence it overwrites the current settings. If you add the new arrow key to it then it works.

```
\path[..., blue, every loop/.append style=-{Latex[length=2mm]}] ...(B) edge[loop]
```

Or you can define this at the top of the picture or as Denis does change the meaning of default arrow `->` to another arrow.